# How to avoid user clicking few times on the OptionsItemSelected button in Android?

Tags: java, android

In my Android project user is clicking few times at button so I want to block that button if it's pressed already. Now SaveOrder() method is fired few times which is not acceptable.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.order_save:
        Log.d("Custom Synchronization", "Click!");
        SaveOrder();

        canQuit = true;
        hasAcceptQuit = true;
        onBackPressed(); // navigate to other acitivty
        return true;
    case R.id.order_adnotation:
        setAdnotationOrder();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a boolean that starts with false like:

```
private static boolean hasPressed = false;
```

And then when calling the SaveOrder method you check for the boolean to be false and change it:

```
if(!hasPressed) {
    SaveOrder();
    hasPressed = true;
}
```

Then, after the execution of the method, you could change the boolean again so the user can call the method again. Be aware that the animation of click will still happen, so consider showing something like a Toast to the user to inform what's going on.

Comment: Well it's not working. When I click 3 times and block hasPressed before SaveOrder(); and then add hasPressed to false at the end of SaveOrder it will fire method SaveOrder 3 times...

Comment: Maybe I can set hasPressed to true when I am leaving current activity. To leave it I use onBackPressed()

Comment: Didn't you mean set hasPressed to false? Well, it depends on your app, try it to see if it works.

Comment: Well onCreate activity I add hasPressed to false and it's working fine. Anyway thank you for simple solution. I was thinking about setting disable on Button but didn't know how to set OptionsItem to disabled.